# UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'user_id'

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore

Been getting the error:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/p~clubs-cs50/1.389022909265479577/templates/my_profile.html", line 11, in top-level template code
    {% if user.user_id() == person.identity %}
UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'user_id'
```

When I am trying to get the data from the GAE datastore for my profile info. (I have a similar problem inputting the info? I asked in another question.)

It was working at some point of time and I have no idea what broke it. :/

Controller:

```
def get(self):
    people = Person.query()

    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Logout'
    else:
        url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Login'

    template_values = {
        'user': user,
        'people': people
    }
    template= JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/my_profile.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

template:

```
{% for person in people %}
  {% if person.name %}
    {% if user.user_id() == person.identity %}
      <h1>!!!!!!!!</h1>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  <br><h3>Name: {{ person.name }}</h3>
  <h3>Email: {{person.email}}</h3>
  <h3>Class Year: {{person.year}}</h3>
  <h3>Bio: {{person.bio}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

(Where !!!!s are to imply it's the user's info and everyone else's bios are displayed for now.)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: read the traceback, `'None' has no attribute 'user_id'`, so `user` contain None value.

Comment: Does the code have this line?  `from google.appengine.api import users`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps change this line:

```
{% if user.user_id() == person.identity %}
```

to this:

```
{% if user and user.user_id() == person.identity %}
```

Comment: The bios are now displayed but it doesn't identify the user. (i.e. when I'm logged in, it doesn't display "!!!!!s" but presents my bio like it were just another entry.) This is like how it was before I broke it. 
You can go on clubs-cs50.appspot.com to take a look at what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Yep so then you have some problem with how you are getting the current user, or the current user id doesn't match person.identity

Comment: I just don't understand where the problem is/how I can find it :(
Everything seems to match up in the create profile form (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101780/attributeerror-function-object-has-no-attribute-user-id).

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [Using the Users Service](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/usingusers.html#the-users-api):

> If the user is already signed in to your application,
>   get_current_user() returns the User object for the user. Otherwise, it
>   returns None

It appears that your user has not logged in yet.